# PySpark read csv reading last empty column value as double quote instead of none when escape character is empty

Tags: python, csv, pyspark

I'm using read.csv() method in [pyspark.sql.SparkSession](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.SparkSession.html) to read a csv file into pySpark dataframe.
The data in csv files is unescaped. So, I am setting the escape character as empty ''.

```
data_frame = spark_session.read.csv(csv_file_name, escape='',  sep=',', quote='"')
```

This is causing a problem when reading csv with last column as empty string
For example, for file with content

```
"","",""
```

The output dataframe is

```
+----+----+---+
|_c0 |_c1 |_c2|
+----+----+---+
|null|null|"  |
+----+----+---+
```

instead of

```
+----+----+----+
|_c0 |_c1 |_c2 |
+----+----+----+
|null|null|null|
+----+----+----+
```

When I try the same input with python's csv library the parsing works as expected.

```
>>> import csv
>>> with open(csv_file_name) as csvfile:
...   spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', escapechar='')
...   for row in spamreader:
...     print(row)
```

prints

```
['', '', '']
```

I am trying to understand why pyspark csv reader is behaving this way.

Comment: I want to double-check what you've written.  What you're showing is 5 characters: double-quote, comma, double-quote, comma, double-quote.  That would be invalid.  The first field would be a quoted comma, the second field would be unterminated.  Are those actually six single quotes?  Because you told Spark that you were using double-quotes for quoting.  Should you be saying `quote = "'"`?

Comment: It was wrongly written as ",",". Corrected to "","","". Thanks.

Comment: There's no reason for this.  Is it possible you have a DOS/Unix newline confusion?  You might try playing with `lineSep` or `ignoreTrailingWhiteSpace`.

Comment: I did try playing with lineSep. Will give ignoreTrailingWhiteSpace a shot. What's confounding me is that with native python csv library the parsing is working fine for the same file with the same csv config.